# Can't install Windows 7 on Acer Aspire M1100

Tags: windows-7, bios, acer-aspire

When I install Windows 7, everything goes smooth but as soon as it's done and Windows needs to reboot for the last time before getting the desktop, the computer stucks to Verify DMI Pool Data............. and then, nothing.

I change the CMOS battery, I tried so many setup in BIOS, even load default settings... Nothing worked. The HDD light is not flickering anymore, no HDD activity. CTRL-ALT-DEL doesn't work. It's just impossible to load Windows 7.

I tried Windows XP and this works fine. I also tried the Acer (Futureshop) recovery CD and I get an Hexademical error message stating the install cannot continue.

Is there a BIOS flash apps somewhere or a fix I can apply to have Windows 7 Ultimate installed on my computer.

Any takers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the upgrade advisor to see if there is a known hardware issue? [Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1B544E90-7659-4BD9-9E51-2497C146AF15&displaylang=en)

Did it ship with Vista?

Is AHCI mode enabled in BIOS?

Comment: Windows 7 is just not compatible on this computer. BIOS settings are all good because Vista loads without problems on this PC. Thanks for the answer! +25 for you and +10 for me ? ;) joke!

Comment: Wait.. what? "Not compatible"? What gives?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before try AHCI drivers first....
You will need to find out your system specs and determine the HDD type
then google for AHCI drivers and download them

--- Using Nlite you need to incorporate AHCI drivers (7 or 9 usually) into the Win7 Installation disk and then make it bootable again ....
\

Answer (score 1):

I also faced exactly the same issue on the same model. I also followed the same suggestions to fix the boot sector, used many partition utilities and spent roughly the same time as the OP. Looking at the specs for the Aspire M1100 motherboard, it seems to suggest that only XP and Vista are compatible:

[M1100 Specs](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/desktop/0000/Acer/aspirem1100/aspirem1100sp2.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Repairing The Windows 7 Installation might fix it

1. Insert the Windows 7 DVD and restart your computer
2. Boot from the DVD
3. Choose your language and click `[Next]`
4. Click *Repair Your Computer* and then select the operating system you want to repair

If that doesn’t work:

1. Insert the Windows 7 DVD and restart your computer
2. Boot from the DVD
3. Choose your language and click `[Next]`
4. Click *Repair Your Computer* and then select *Command Prompt* and try the following commands (a single command might work, or you may need to use multiple). Note, there is a space before the `/`

   ```
   bootrec /fixMBR
   bootrec /fixBoot
   bootrec /rebuildBCD
   bootrec /scanOS
   ```

Comment: All of these have been tested. I spent over 30h trying to fix that but it's clearly listed on Acer's website that Windows 7 can't be installed on that machine...

Answer (score 0):

I installed Windows 7 without an issue on an Acer M1100 that used to run Vista.  I backed up my files then wiped out all partitions and created a separate partition to host the boot files and another partition for the rest of the the system files.  It is running fine without any issues.